# How to create a Generic method that can instantiate multiple objects and put them into a List

Tags: java, list, generics, immutability

I'm trying to create a small function that will take a variable amount of objects, instantiate them and add them to a List.

I personally want to use this for `String`, `BigDecimal` and `Long`.

I feel I am close with the following function:

```
<T> List<T> createGenericList(Class<T> clazz, T ...params) throws Exception {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T param : params) {
        Constructor<T> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(clazz);
        T instance = constructor.newInstance(param);
        list.add(instance);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This works great for `String`:

```
createGenericList(String.class,"a","b")
```

But not for `BigDecimal` or `Long`

```
createGenericList(BigDecimal.class,10,10);
```

Because Java is reading my numbers as `int`.  Casting doesn't seem to work either.

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Integer conforms to BigDecimal 
inference variable T has incompatible bounds:
equality constraints: BigDecimal
lower bounds: Integer
```

I was also looking at `ImmutableList.of(...)` but I seem to have the same issue with numbers.

Comment: My goal is to avoid typing `new` for each additional parameter I need to pass.  I originally had separate functions for each object.  Seeing as 3 different functions did almost the same thing I am attempting to learn if there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a `Function<P, T>` to the method:

```
<P, T> List<T> createGenericList(Function<? super P, ? extends T> func, List<? extends P> params) throws Exception {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (P param : params) {
        T instance = func.apply(param);
        list.add(instance);
    }
    return list;
}
```

And then invoke like:

```
List<ParamType> params = Arrays.asList(param1, param2);
List<SomeType> list = createGenericList(SomeType::new, params);
```

(Assuming `SomeType` has a constructor taking a single `ParamType`; but this will fail at compile time if it doesn't)

Comment: @JornVernee you *could*, but then you're potentially creating a generic array. Arrays and generics are unhappy bedfellows.

Comment: I saw you changed the signature in your edit. The two versions are equivalent and it was simpler before the edit.

Comment: @cppbeginner no, they're not equivalent. You can write `TheClass.<ParamType, SomeType>createGenericList(func, Arrays.asList(subclassOfParamType))` with the code I've got here, but not with what was there before.

Comment: Ok that's true, but there's no point in doing that because you could get that to compile by writing the correct type arguments. They're equivalent in the sense that they both accept precisely the same pairs of arguments (assuming you write the correct  type arguments).

Comment: The way to prove that is to write 2 methods with the different signatures then change the body of each method to simply call the other one. Since both calls compile (I checked this) it means the second signature is in fact not more general than the first.